# How to give access to user for specifig directory?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, apache-http-server, symbolic-link

I made symlink when logged in as `www` (apache user):

```
ln -s /home/anotheruser/test /var/www/test
```

Now I go to my `mydomain.com/test` and I get  a 403 error.

`/home/anotheruser/` has permissions 764 (group read + write and public read)
otheruser and www are in the same group.

So, what permissions do I have to give to the `/home/anotheruser` folder to make this work?

Comment: A directory permission without the `x` bit makes the directory essentially useless.  Thus the 764 should really be 775.

Comment: For first time change permissions of all of file and directory you working with to 777, To determine that Where we have problem.

Comment: Okay, I still got this problem even if permissions are set to 777.

Comment: @SepahradSalour http://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive

Comment: The question is not clear at all. Please reproduce **exactly** the commands you executed, and please show us: `id otheruser` `id www` `ls -lrtd /var/www/test/` `ls -lrtd /home/anotheruser/test`. Also, the `ln -s` command is wrong.

Comment: @Dawud: It just for test. Not for ever :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have apache configured to follow Symbolic Links

Example Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin SomeUser@SuperUser.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
<VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This HTTP error may not be file system related per se, you can either chose to list all filesusually:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ...
     <Directory>
       Options +Indexes
     </Directory>   
     ...
   </VirtualHost>
```

Would do the trick, else you can try to access a file directly from that directory, if there's no security settings such as chroot or so.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit long, but I think the background is important here, so please bear with me.

### Reason for the problem

When you're using a symlink, what you're saying is essentially "instead of looking here (/var/www/test), you should look at that directory over there (/home/anotheruser/test)". In order for that to work when serving web files, you need two things:

- the user that apache runs as must be allowed to read that directory - that part you've got correct already with the help from the others
- apache must be configured to allow it to serve files from that directory - and this is the part that's missing.

To take an example: The file /etc/passwd is readable for everyone. Still, you probably don't want it readable for the entire world - so even if you were to make a symlink (`ln -s /etc/passwd /var/www/test/passwd`), it still would not be readable unless you specifically tell apache that it's allowed to server files from /etc.

### How to fix this

You need to either move the files to a directory that apache is allowed to server pages from, or you need to allow apache to serve pages from the directory where the files live.

#### Solution 1 - move files

The quickest solution is to turn the symlink around - create the directory `/var/www/test`, make anotheruser the owner, and do `ln -s /var/www/test /home/anotheruser/`. That way all files are actually stored under `/var/www`, so apache is allowed to serve them.

#### Solution 2 - allow directory

Add a directive to httpd.conf to allow apache to serve content from `/home/anotheruser/test`. Then just remove the symlink and set up an alias instead. Like this:

```
Alias /test /home/anotheruser/test

<Directory /home/anotheruser/test>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```